# Is it possible to prove the positive root of the equation ${^4}x=2$, $x=1.4466014324...$ is irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers, exponentiation, tetration, transcendental-equations

(somewhat related to my [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373881/is-the-positive-root-of-the-equation-xxx-2-x-1-47668433-a-transcende))

Let ${^n}a$ denote [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) $\underbrace{a^{a^{.^{.^{.^a}}}}}_{n \text{ times}}$ (or, defined recursively, ${^1}a=a$, ${^{n+1}}a=a^{({^n}a)}$).

The equation ${^4}x=2$ has a positive root $x=1.4466014324...$

Is it possible to prove it irrational?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a known open problem. It is also open for all equations of the form ${^n q}=2$ or ${^n q}=3$ for integer $n>3$. For $n=3$ the roots are known to be irrational, but not known to be algebraic or transcendental.