# transcendental numbers as solutions to hyperpowers

Tags: transcendental-numbers

By the Gelfond-Schneider theorem,
if $x^x=2$, $x$ must be transcendental. What can be said of $x$ if $x^{x^x}=2$, $x^{x^{x^x}}=2$ etc.? Must it be transcendental? Of course, $2$ can be replaced by any algebraic number.
Henry Harry Lande M Sc

Comment: This is open as far as I know, it's been asked before here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373881/is-the-positive-root-of-the-equation-xxx-2-x-1-47668433-a-transcende?rq=1 I think everyone expects the answer to be yes but it's out of reach.

Comment: What is the distinction between x and X ?